# What sources to add in order to install cuda toolkit with apt on Debian?

Tags: debian, apt, source, cuda

I am new to Debian and I want to install the **NVIDIA CUDA toolkit**, 
so I typed:

```
apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

but it did not work, I found out I need to add a source in **/etc/apt/sources.list** which contains this CUDA package.

However, as for now there are only a few lines in **/etc/apt/sources.list** referring to a university, which I chose during installation.

I do not know how to find out which source I need to add.

Is there a Debian database, where I can submit the program I need and which in turn gives me a list of sources containing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`nvidia-cuda-toolkit`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/devel/nvidia-cuda-toolkit) package is a `non-free` software , edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by adding the `non-free` component :

```
apt edit-sources
```

Then edit your sources , there is an example:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
```

save and run:

```
apt update
apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

[Component](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Component)

> main consists of [DFSG](https://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelines)-compliant packages, which do not rely on software outside this area to operate. These are the only packages considered part of the Debian distribution.
>
> contrib packages contain DFSG-compliant software, but have dependencies not in main (possibly packaged for Debian in non-free).
>
> non-free contains software that does not comply with the DFSG.

Comment: thank you very much, could anybody comment on what the "stretch main contrib non-free"-part means?